# How to pop an alert dialog on Flutter from outside the builder

Tags: dart, flutter

Consider my scenario

```
//Show the progress indicator inside an alert to block the user
showAlertProgressIndicator(); 

// Get the data
await DataManager.get().getDummyData().then((value){
      // After data acquisition pop the alertProgressIndicator
});
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it should be simple
`Navigator.pop(context);` or

```
void closeAlert() {
  Navigator.pop(context);//it will close last route in your navigator
}
```

I guess these 2 methods in the same `build()`. So they have the same `BuildContext`, so above should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample app related to this situation. It is here https://github.com/Yahhi/flutter_dialog_test
Context is the same and dialog disappears after 5 seconds on timer event.

```
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
```